# University Exam question about "Systems of Particles"

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, projectile

I am doing an old exam where I encountered this question, and no matter what I try to throw at it. I cannot solve it
(This is from the Chapter "Systems of Particles, which composes of Center of mass, Conservation of momentum and Kinetic Energy, and collisions)

**The question**: On the top of a 100m height cliff, an object weighted 6,4kg is thrown out with speed 54,0 m/s at 52° to horizon. It explodes into 2 pieces during the flight. One piece weighted 4,2kg and is located at 224m away from the bottom of the cliff. If these 2 pieces hit the ground at the same time, please find:
**The location of the second piece from the bottom of the cliff**.

I just don't know what to do with it.
I have tried:

Using conservation of momentum and Kinetic Energy, but since is an explosion, and doesn't have conservation of Kinetic Energy. I don't know if it can be done this way.

Using projectile motion in addition to conservation of momentum, but I always find that I am missing  data to solve it.

I have also tried assuming different angles for the two fragments in relation to each other to somehow find a ratio, but I was also unsuccessful.

One idea that I think it might work (but I have so far not been able to use it) is using the center of mass of the two fragments? since they both impact at the same time. On final Velocity they should make a straight line parallel to the X axis?

Comment: It's best practice to wait about 24 hours before accepting an answer.  This way you can have a chance to receive multiple answers and benefit from seeing the up/down votes of others.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for the tip. I did not think about that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final idea using both the center of mass (CoM) of the system and conservation of momentum is on the right track.

For a system of particles, we can break the motion into two parts:

- center of mass motion
- relative motion

During the explosion the net force on the system is zero.
The force of one piece on the second is equal and opposite to the force of the second back on the first by Newton's third law.
This is why the system's total momentum is conserved during the explosion, and it is also why the center of mass of the system will follow the projectile's original trajectory.

In the end we don't care about the details of the relative motion, just the relative final position of each piece.  If you know the final location of the CoM and the final location of one piece, you can determine the final location of the other.

Comment: An essential - but rather unlikely - condition in the question is that the two pieces reach the ground at the same time. Otherwise the COM will not remain on the original trajectory.